# ¿Por qué en España no se usa el español a la hora de listar los ingredientes de productos cosméticos?

Tags: españa, legislación

En España es obligatorio por ley el listar en español los ingredientes de todo producto de alimentación que se venda en cualquier tienda. Esto se nota sobre todo en productos de importación, que suelen llevar una pegatina con la traducción de los ingredientes y de algunas instrucciones de preparación o uso.

Sin embargo, en los productos cosméticos esto no es así:

[image: Ingredients]

¿Por qué esto es así? No tengo claro el porqué, no sé si es porque los ingredientes suelen ser compuestos químicos, pero cuando yo estudié química en el colegio la formulación se hacía en español, y no en inglés. ¿Existe alguna normativa europea que regule los textos que incluyan compuestos químicos que no permita que se use la traducción al español de los mismos?

Comment: Parece más una pregunta sobre legislación del país que sobre lenguaje. (y se me hace curiosos que tengamos una etiqueta "legislación")

Comment: @DGaleano la etiqueta la acabo de crear yo. :-) Sí, sé que la pregunta no es sobre el lenguaje en sí, pero sí sobre algo relacionado con el mismo. Es como cuando hacemos preguntas sobre la RAE: no son sobre el lenguaje en sí sino sobre algo relacionado. Pensaba que así podríamos dar cabida a un nuevo tipo de preguntas en el sitio.

Comment: Lo mismo sucede en Argentina, siempre me pregunté la razón.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclatura_International_de_Ingredientes_Cosm%C3%A9ticos):

> La INCI (International Nomenclature of Cosmetic Ingredients), es un sistema de nombres para ceras, aceites, pigmentos, químicos, y otros ingredientes de jabones, cosméticos, entre otros, **basados en nombres científicos y otros lenguajes, como el latín e Inglés. Los nombres INCI a menudo difieren de los nombres sistemáticos IUPAC o de referencias comunes.**
> ...
> **Este nombre universal debe aparecer en los rótulos de los productos cosméticos en la mayoría de los países.**
> ...
> En España, la Agencia Española de Medicamentos y Productos Sanitarios, en su página pública la lista de nombres INCI.

Por otro lado, el artículo 33 de "**REGULATION (EC) No 1223/2009 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL of 30 November 2009 on cosmetic products**" (http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02009R1223-20150416&from=EN) indica que:

> The Commission shall compile and update a glossary of common ingredient names. To this end, the Commission shall take account of internationally recognised nomenclatures including the International Nomenclature of Cosmetic Ingredients (INCI). That glossary shall not constitute a list of the substances authorised for use in cosmetic products.
>
> The common ingredient name shall be applied for the purpose of labelling cosmetic products placed on the market at the latest twelve months after publication of the glossary in the Official Journal of the European Union.

Por lo que parece que, efectivamente, es por normativa europea.

Comment: ¡Grandiosa entrada al foro! ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]!